# what is difference between message_generation and genmsg?

Tags: ros, genmsg, catkin, message-generation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

what is difference between message_generation and genmsg?

[CreatingMsgAndSrv tutorial]
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs message_generation)

[WritingPublisherSubscriber tutorial]
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs genmsg)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65236/what-is-difference-between-message_generation-and-genmsg?/) by [Pyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/632/pyo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 358 on 2013-06-14

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`genmsg` contains only the abstract message generation functionality.

`message_generation` depends on `genmsg` and the specific generators for languages ROS supports out-of-the-box: `gencpp`, `genlisp` and `genpy`. It is similiar to the former `langs` / `langs-dev` packages.

As a message package you always want to depend on `message_generation`.

Update: I have filled https://github.com/ros/catkin_tutorials/issues/8 to make sure the outdated tutorial gets updated.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/632/pyo/) on 2013-06-15**:
It's helpful for me. Thanks. :)

**Comment by [marilia15](https://answers.ros.org/users/5506/marilia15/) on 2015-03-21**:
It is not updated in the tutorial yet.
[WritingPublisherSubscriber tutorial] still has genmsg instead of message_generation.

Furthermore in [CreatingMsgAndSrv tutorial] in the point 4, there is an error.

```
# In your catkin workspace
$ cd ../..   <=== SHOULD BE REMOVED.
$ catkin_make
```